# Error .zip containing multiple .pdf files using JSZip

Tags: javascript, angular, zip

I do not know the use of the JSZip library, and if with it you can ask the question I ask.

The idea I had was something like this:

```
generateZip() {
const a = ['arraybase64example'];

const zip = new JSZip();

Array.from(a)
  .forEach(file => {
    zip.file("prueba", file)
  })

  return zip.generateAsync({
    type: 'arraybuffer', // changed from blob to arrayBuffer
    compression: 'DEFLATE',
    compressionOptions: {
      level: 9
    }
  }).then(function (content) {
    window.location.href = content; // Type 'ArrayBuffer' cannot be assigned to type 'string'
  });
}
```

**I can't download the .zip file from browser** in relation to the global window object.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this code snippet. Customize it as per your needs.

```
const files = [{ name: "hello", content: "world" }]
const zipFile: JSZip = new JSZip()

files.forEach(file => zipFile.file<"string">(file.name, file.content))

zipFile.generateAsync<"blob">({ type: "blob" })
    .then(blob => {
        const a   : HTMLAnchorElement = this.renderer.createElement("a")
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

        this.renderer.setProperty(a, "href", url)
        this.renderer.setProperty(a, "download", "file.zip")

        a.click()
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
    })
```

### Explanation

1. Create a zip file object
2. Add files to the object
3. Generate a `Blob` of the zip file
4. Create an anchor tag
5. Generate a URL for the `Blob`
6. Add the URL to the anchor tag
7. Click the anchor tag programmatically to start the download process
8. Remove the URL

---

**Note 1:** Here I have used the `Renderer2` service because I think we shouldn't be interacting with the DOM directly.

**Note 2:** You'll need to inject the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) service in your component.